# hiding or showing a div depending on values fetched from a database

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table with a column of registration. When user logs into his/her account, a value of unregistered is inserted into the registration column. The user then proceeds and register his/her account and the value in the registration column is updated to registered.

I need to return true when the user is registered and change the value in a particular div from unregistered to registered and hide the registration link to the page for registration using Jquery as in code three. In addition return false when the user is unregistered.

The code one below is functioning when i manually change the id of the user as shown below but when I use the users' id in session as shown in code two,only return false is executed.I need a person to assist me please. The jquery code below is functioning with php code one.

Code one is functioning but the id's I have to change them manually.

**code one**

```
<?php
    require'connection.php';//connection to the database

    if(isset($_GET['register']))
    {
    $user_id='15';//registered,if use this id it returns true;
    $user_id='14';//unregistered,if i use this id it returns false;


    $register=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['register']));

    $query="select `account_id` from `user_account` where `register`='$register' and `account_id`='$user_id'";
    if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
        $row=mysql_num_rows($query_run);

            if($row == 1){
                echo 'registered';
            }
                else if($row== 0){
            echo 'unregistered';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Code two does not execute.

**code two**

```
<?php
    require'connection.php';//connection to the database
    require'user_getfield.php';//function to get user data in session,functioning

    if(isset($_GET['register']))
    {
    $user_id=$_SESSION['user_id'];

    $register=mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_GET['register']));

    $query="select `account_id` from `user_account` where `register`='$register' and `account_id`='$user_id'";
    if($query_run=mysql_query($query)){
        $row=mysql_num_rows($query_run);

            if($row == 1){
                echo 'registered';
            }
                else if($row== 0){
            echo 'unregistered';
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Code three below is the jquery code. When a return true is executed,the div value changes from unregistered to registered and the registration link is hidden from the being accessed.

**jquery code three**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var register='registered';

    $.get('php/AjaxFinishRegistration.php',{register:register},function(data)
    {
        if(data=='registered')
        {
            $('#welcome_div').html('YOU ARE REGISTERED').css('background','blue');  
            $('#AccountRegister,#registration').hide();     
        }
        else if(data=='unregistered'){
            $('#welcome_div').html('FINISH REGISTRATION').css('background','red');
            $('#CreateGig').attr('value','disabled');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` loaded? Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) 
`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Don't use `htmlentities()` when putting into the database. It should only be used when displaying on a web page.

Comment: You could do a bit better job error checking. It would be nice to know why the code wasn't executing and where.

Comment: I have set my session in the user_getfield.php,i have excluded htmlentities and still is returning false

Comment: Since the only difference between the two scripts is the way you set `$user_id`, the problem is obviously with the session variable. You need to figure out why `$_SESSION['user_id']` isn't getting set. There's no way for us to tell this from the code you've posted.

Comment: @user3800343 can you post the code for `user_getfield.php` ?

Comment: The code two is returning correct values but on inclusion of an id in session,it is returning false meaning it is not working well but the User_getfield.php is correctly returning the details of the user logged in

Comment: @user3800343 you don't only want for `user_getfield.php` to return the correct values but also to set the session

Comment: Okey let me try your solutions please.

Comment: Thanks guys it has worked.